# Gettig all posst of categories with child categories in hierarchical form

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in our web application we have multiple nested categories which they are `belongsToMany` with `posts`, each posts can be assign one or multiple categories and now, i want to get all posts from parent to end of sub categories which assigned into this tree

with below code i can get all this categories in hierarchical, but i can't save all posts to return as output:

```php
$category = Category::whereId($request->category_id)->whereNull('category_id')->with('childrenCategories')->first();
$this->allCategories($category,$request);

/******************************************/
private function allCategories($category){
    if($category->childrenCategories->first()){
        foreach ($category->childrenCategories as $childCategory) {
            ...
            $this->allCategories($childCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

my models:

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function parentCategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Category::class, 'category_id', 'id' );
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function childrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class)->with('categories');
    }
}


class Post extends Model
{
    use Sluggable, SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for querying recursive relationships? https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list works great for that. It'll help you get the tree you want.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman thanks, in that `belongsToMany` not support

Comment: Right, well in that case you might need to write your own recursive CTE to traverse the hierarchy. But than you'll also need to implement your own eloquent logic.